# Local module giving ModuleNotFoundError when run inside conda virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I am trying to run a simple import of a module from an adjacent python file and I keep getting a 'ModuleNotFoundError' This is what the files look like from the same directory:

test1.py:
`temp = 0`

test2.py: `from test1 import temp`

When I run `python3 test2.py` from the terminal when the conda environment has not been activated, I am able to retrieve temp. However, when the environment is active, I start getting the ModuleNotFound error. How can I fix this?

Thanks